# how to convert part of a list to a nested list in python? only use builtin functions

Tags: python

I'm just wondering how to convert a list of strings into a nested list? without module import.
for example:

input ["ABC","1","x","y","z"]

output ["ABC","1",["x","y","z"]]

Comment: How do you decide at what point it stops being a string and becomes an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
mylist = ["ABC","1","x","y","z"]

def nest(mylist, n):
    """Nests list from nth element"""
    nest = [x for x in mylist[n:]]
    mylist = mylist[:n]
    mylist.append(nest)

   return mylist

nest(mylist, 2)
```

Comment: Why ``[x for x in mylist[n:]]`` and not just ``mylist[n:]`` ?

Comment: Yes you're right, that's simpler.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case you could do this:

```
mylist = ["ABC","1","x","y","z"]

offset = 2

newlist = mylist[:offset] + [mylist[offset:]]

print(newlist)
```

**Output:**

```
['ABC', '1', ['x', 'y', 'z']]
```